# Efficient automatic bracket completion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parsing

I'm writing automatic bracket completion feature for a text editor, my current approach is to call a bracket matching procedure (assume it's correct and efficient) on every newline where the last typed symbol is the open bracket, starting from the new line (with that last typed open bracket on the top of the stack) until either the stack is empty or it comes to the end of the source with no matching close bracket found.

However, this approach seems to be slow for big source files (>1 MB), especially when the newline is added at the first half of the source lines (newline at first line = worst case = whole text is scanned). Some IDEs have this capability and could handle it fast, so they must be using different approach. So, I would like to know what algorithm they use or any other approach better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

If matching brackets is an important concern you can handle it using a secondary data structure for brackets alone.

E.g. you can build a tree which stores begin_pos/end_pos for a pair of brackets within a node and as children all pairs of brackets within. Take special care of non-matching brackets (i.e. they start/end at their parents boundaries).

Adding an extra open/close bracket is quite comfortable with such a structure since you can skip all child and sibling trees.

An appropriate implementation should perform with O(log(n)) solution, n being the number of pairs of brackets.

Comment: OK, but I still don't have any idea about the algorithm. When do I add/remove the tree nodes? When do I do the completion? The only clear thing (for me) is the lookup boundary which as far as I understand still have to look till the end of source at the worst case, that is when I add the brace near the beginning of the source. Assuming the inner bracket pairs are complete, then it can only be decided to add the closing bracket or not at the end of the source.

Comment: @LeleDumbo perhaps your question can have more requirements. 
(given enough requirements, a solution is likely dictated)
Are the requirements to just insert `)` after each unmatched `(`? Where not? When not?

Comment: Also, in @Howard approach the worst case of scanning each line really shouldn't be a performance problem as its just a find/lookup in a sorted list, nothing needs to be parsed or processed, just compared.